# Return springs for front disk brakes

Tags: disk-brakes

I'm replacing the front disk brake pads on a 1997 Nissan Wingroad. The service manual shows 2 return springs (similar to those in the attached photo below) for each set of brake pads but when removing the old pads there were none present. As the brakes seemed to be working ok I was wondering how important is it to have them?

[image]

Comment: Are they present in the box with the new pads? If so fit them.

Comment: @SolarMike, haven't bought the new pads yet.

Answer (score 2):

Some vehicles do not use clips for brake pads. Most do. Yours obviously requires them because they are in the manual. Many economy pad sets from the parts store do not include the clips. Get premium pads. They usually include the clips. If not, purchase the front brake hardware kit. The clips will be in that. Clips are important because they allow the pads to move freely. If they stick, they will cause rapid pad wear and ruin the rotors. They also prevent the pads from wearing out the bracket. A worn bracket will cause the pads to stick as well. Be sure to clean bracket under where the clips go very thoroughly. Many times they appear to be clean and they are not. In rust belt areas and on a car this old a wire brush or wire wheel may not be enough to adequately clean them.

Comment: The return springs are similar to those shown in the photo which I added to my original post. Are you talking about the same thing? Where exactly is the bracket you mention?

Comment: Thanks for the picture. I assumed you were talking about the clips that go on the bracket that the pads ride on. I was wrong sorry. But the same advise pertains to the springs. They are included in a hardware kit.